# How do I check if there are duplicates of text in a column in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, conditional-formatting

Lets say that I have a spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc that looks like this:

```
     A          B
1|   1          foo
2|   1          bar
3|   2          foo
4|   1          bar
5|   1          baz
```

I want to conditionally format this so that, if there is a duplicate in two rows of both column A *and* column B, it is formatted in red, and if there is a duplicate between two rows in column B, *but not* column A, it is formatted as yellow.  Otherwise, it is formatted as green.

Using the example before, rows 2 and 4 would be formatted red (because there are duplicates in both columns,) rows 1 and 3 would be formatted yellow (because while it is duplicated in column B, it is not so in column A,) and row 5 is formatted green (because it doesn't satisfy either of the previous conditions.)

How can i use conditional formatting to achieve this effect?

Comment: Shouldn't row 1 be red since it is duplicated in rows 2 and 4? Or do you just want occurences after the first one to be highlighted?

Comment: Row one isn't duplicated in rows two and four, because it's case sensitive.  To clear up confusion, I will edit it.